# Perl Skipping Some Files When Looping Across Files and Writing Their Contents to Output File

Tags: perl

I'm having an issue with Perl and I'm hoping someone here can help me figure out what's going on.  I have about 130,000 .txt files in a directory called `RawData` and I have a Perl program that loads them into an array, then loops through this array, loading each .txt file. For simplicity, suppose I have four text files I'm looping through

```
 File1.txt
 File2.txt
 File3.txt
 File4.txt
```

The contents of each .txt file look something like this:

```
 007 C03XXYY    ZZZZ
 008 A01XXYY    ZZZZ
 009 A02XXYY    ZZZZ
```

where `X,Y,Z` are digits. In my simplified code below, the program then pulls out just line `007` in each .txt file, saves `XX` as `ID`, ignores `YY` and grabs the variable data `ZZZZ` that I've called `VarVal`. Then it writes everything to a file with a header specified in the code below:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use warnings;
 use strict;

 open(OUTFILE, "> ../Data/OutputFile.csv") or die $!;

 opendir(MYDIR,"../RawData")||die $!;
 my @txtfiles=grep {/\.txt$/} readdir(MYDIR);
 closedir(MYDIR);

 print OUTFILE "ID,VarName,VarVal\n";

 foreach my $txtfile (@txtfiles){

        #Prints to the screen so I can see where I am in the loop.
        print $txtfile","\n";

        open(INFILE, "< ../RawData/$txtfile") or die $!;

        while(<INFILE>){

             if(m{^007 C03(\d{2})(\d+)(\s+)(.+)}){
                print OUTFILE "$1,VarName,$4\n"
        }
             }
        }
```

The issue I'm having is that the contents of, for example `File3.txt`, don't show up in `OutputFile.csv`. However, it's not an issue with Perl not finding a match because I checked that the `if` statement is being executed by deleting `OUTFILE` and looking at what the code prints to the terminal screen.  What shows up is exactly what should be there.

Furthermore, If I just run the problematic file (`File3.txt`) through the loop itself by commenting out the `opendir` and `closedir` stuff and doing something like `my @textfile = "File3.txt";`. Then when I run the code, the only data that shows up in the `OutputFile.csv` IS what's in `File3.txt`. But when it goes through the loop, it won't show up in `OutputFile.csv`. Plus, I know that `File3.txt` is being sent to into the loop because I can see it being printed on the screen with `print $txtfile","\n";`. I'm at a loss as to what is going on here.

The other issue is that I don't think it's something specific to this one particular file (maybe it is) but I can't just troubleshoot this one file because I have 130,000 files and I just happened to stumble across the fact that this one wasn't being written to the output file. So there may be other files that also aren't getting written, even though there is no obvious reason they shouldn't be just like the case of `File3.txt`.

Perhaps because I'm doing so many files in rapid succession, looping 130,000 files, causes some sort of I/O issues that randomly fails every so often to write the contents in memory to the output file? That's my best guess but I have not idea how to diagnose or fix this.

This is kind of a difficult question to debug, but I'm hoping someone on here has some insight or has seen similar problems that would provide me with a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing obviously wrong that I can see in your code.  It is a little outdated as using [autodie](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) and lexical filehandles would be better.

However, I would recommend that you make your regex slightly less restrictive by making the spacing variable length after the first value and making the last variable optionally of 0 length.  I'd also output the filename as well.  Then you can see which other files aren't being caught for whatever reason:

```
if (m{^007\s+C03(\d{2})\d+\s+(.*)}){
    print OUTFILE "$txtfile $1,VarName,$2\n";
    last;
}
```

Finally, assuming there is only a single `007 C03` in each file, you could throw in a `last` call after one is found.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I ran my code over a slice of the `@txtfiles` array that was only about 20,000 files and contained the one file I know to be excluded in the full 130,000 run. In this case the data for `File3.txt` does show up in the output file. So I'm thinking it has something to do with Perl loosing data in memory  when looping through a large number of files. Do you have any insight into that? The files themselves are small (>=38MB).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try sorting the @txtfiles list, then trying to systematically look through the output to see what is or isn't there.  With 130k files in random order, it would be pretty difficult to be certain that you missed one.  Perl should be giving you the files in the actual order they appear in the directory, which is different that user level commands like ls, so it may be different that you'd expect.